# UITableView inside a UITableViewCell? What's the best design?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've not found a answer to this question anywhere, but this seems like a typical problem: I am dynamically (from a xml file) creating a view to display "Questions" I take from the XML file. I am having problems to display multiple choice questions. I am trying following approach:

```
Question 1
MultipleChoiceQuestion 2
--First Option
--Second Option
--Third Option
Question 3
Question 4
MultipleChoiceQuestion 5
--First Option
--Second Option
and so on...
```

So, my Idea is: I have a first UITableView and row for each "normal" question , and a second UITableView for each "Multiple Choice" question that should be loaded into a row from the first UITableView as I showed before.

Is this a good approach or you guys have a better design pattern for this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no! Please, no! Do not place big UI Elements like table views in a tableviewcell (and surely do not make them scrollable =P).

What about making the user be able to select a question (one question per row) and then show up a picker view with answers, on the place where to keyboard would normally be?

Just like a list of HTML select tags in Mobile Safari.

---

Or you can use a grouped table view with one group per question, including the chosable answers.

Comment: +1 Or just custom cells. Calculating the height is not that hard. Golden rule: If you think a problem is common but nobody has done it that way before, there's a probably a good reason for it.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer Baard. I can't use a Picker, cause the User should be able to choose more than one option. So, I am gonna try your second recommendation: grouped table view with one group per question!

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as accepted if it helped you ;)

Also, sketching your app idea and UI on paper with a pencil (or on a stone with a hammer) before creating your final app in Xcode/IB helps you prevent these frustrations.

Comment: See http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-offline-utensils-and-toolkits-for-designers/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287898/what-advantages-does-sketching-a-user-interface-on-paper-have for sketching information.

Comment: or if they click on a question show a new table view controller with the choices? PS +1 to the answer purely for the first sentance!

Comment: It seems perfectly logical to use a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell. Just make sure you disable scrolling. Example of a need for this behavior: I have a requirement where we have a UITableViewCell that on one half shows a list of dynamic data (could be 0-10 items, but won't change after it loads) and the other side has a single UIImageView. I could go about dynamically showing, hiding, and adjusting UILabel's but a UITableView is 100 times easier.

Answer (score 10):

There is a tutorial for creating custom UITableViewCells with UITableView inside it at:
http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/

iOS SDK is flexible and you can add any UIView subclass element to tableview cells. Have a look at 'Pulse', its a news reader app that won Apple Design Award. This app has horizontally scrollable images and its developers explained that how they used UITableViews to create that. So don't be afraid to implement new ideas no matter how wild they might appear.

Good Luck!